# LDRB Instruction with arrays and strings

Tags: assembly, arm

We are currently covering assembly basics in class. There are two example code snippets, pertaining to arrays and strings respectively, that use the LDRB instruction that wasn't used anywhere else. I understand it loads a byte instead of a word like LDR, but I don't understand why it is used where it is used. There is no clarification given in the materials for the class. I tried googling it but I couldn't find anything.

I don't know why it's used, whether it's something specific to arrays and strings or proper syntax... I would greatly appreciate explanations as I want to understand. The code examples are as follows:

Array:

```
.text

entry:    b start

arr:     .byte 10, 20, 25

eoa:

         .align

start:
ldr       r0, =eoa
ldr       r1, =arr
mov       r3, #0

loop:
          ldrb  r2, [r1], #1
          add   r3, r2, r3
          cmp   r1, r0
          bne   loop

stop:
          b stop
```

String:

```
.text
        b start

str:    .asciz "Greetings and well met"

       .equ   nul, 0

       .align

start:

       ldr   r0, =str
       mov   r1, #0

loop:   
       ldrb  r2, [r0], #1
       add   r1, r1, #1
       cmp   r2, #nul
       bne   loop
       sub   r1, r1,#1

stop:   b stop
```

Comment: It's used because strings are made up of bytes not words. Obviously byte arrays too.

Comment: So it's just loading the string/array byte by byte into R2?

Comment: Yes, that is correct. Use your debugger/simulator to see it for yourself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I don't know why it's used, whether it's something specific to arrays and strings or proper syntax... I would greatly appreciate explanations as I want to understand.

---

### LDR vs LDRB

The main reason that you need `ldrb` is that it can address a byte.  The RAM is a cell and it has an intrinsic size that depends on the hardware.  The `ldrb` has ways to ignore portions when loading and writing.  If you use memory mapped hardware register you may find that they behave differently and you need to access them in different ways.

Things are much harder if you think about `str` and `strb`.  If you use `str` for bytes, you would over-write other bytes.

### Array vs String

Generally an array can be sizes other than 'byte'.  However, your example is a *byte array*.  The difference is that byte arrays need to store a size and a string has a reserved character '\x00' that is the end marker.  In the code example, the address label **eoa** is used to mark the end of the array.  Another way to do this is,

```
arr:     .word 1b-arr-4     #  Store size of array first
         .byte 10, 20, 25
1:
```

So the string example is looking for zero with `cmp r2, #nul` and the array example is looking for the size with `cmp r1, r0` (r1 is the current string index and r0 is *eoa*).  The array can allow for the zero character in the data and the string code is a little more compact in representation (`=str` versus `=arr` plus `=eoa`).

The string is similar to a [Communications protocol](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Communication_protocol) concept called escaping and reserved characters.  For example [the character EOS=`\x7e`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/High-Level_Data_Link_Control#Framing) could be the end of a string and the ESCAPE=`\x7d` is reserved.  Then the combination of ESCAPE-!EOS is an EOS in the string and ESC-!ESC is an ESC in the string.  The string has a EOS=`\x00` and a rule that it can not occur so escaping is not needed.  Escaping has a down side that the data size is not the same as the represented size (some data takes two bytes and other only one).  This is also true if the string was Unicode (UTF8, UTF16, etc).

Comment: The last part is not really ARM/assembler specific.  It is a **data structure** issue.  Each data structure usually has trade-offs.  There are lots of ways to represent *text* or *bytes*.  The example seems to confound the two slightly. `ldr r0, =eoa` is a [pseudo-op](https://sourceware.org/binutils/docs/as/ARM-Opcodes.html#ARM-Opcodes) and actually adds data.  Your professor would have more fairly explained the two data structures by example if they had been explicit about the size.